# QGIS Source Code Build

Tags: build, qgis, prerequisites

following the QGIS Install guide

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html

I downloaded all the required packages on Windows and created a Build directory, trying to configure the source code on CMake I get this error :

```
""
QGIS version: 2.11.0 Master (21100)

Could not find GRASS 6

Could not find GRASS 7
GEOS_INCLUDE_DIR=GEOS_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND

GEOS_LIBRARY=GEOS_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND

CMake Error at cmake/FindGEOS.cmake:182 (MESSAGE):

  Could not find GEOS

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  CMakeLists.txt:193 (FIND_PACKAGE)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/QGIS/build/QGIS/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/QGIS/build/QGIS/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

""
```

I cannot proceed to the next step, how do I fix this?

Comment: What OS is it? Windows?

Answer (score 0):

When downloading packages using OSGeo4W just type "grass" in it then click it so that it changes to "Install".

I too selected it but it did not install it .. I had to select it again to install.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standalone installer found at http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Download.

Then, set up a GRASS Database through the "Plugins > Grass > New Mapset" menu.